# Feature engineering for anomaly detection when feature is directional

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, anomaly-detection

I want to train an anomaly detection model for intrusion and fraud detection. I have several features I know are correlated with sketchy behavior. However, those features are "directional" and anomalies should only be considered relevant if the feature value is high.

For example, if velocity of transactions was a feature were the bulk of the mass was at "average" velocity, I imagine the anomaly detector would return outliers with both low and high values.

Is there  a good way to encode directionality in the features or in the model, such to enforce that a feature value should only be considered anomalous if the value is high?

Answer (score 1):

These kind of constraints on what is a 'valid' anomaly can be done as either a pre-processing or post-processing step.

In either case you will need to come up with a definition of "only if above normal". One approach might be a transformation like such:

```py
f1_above_typical = max(0, f1-median(f1))
```

Median could be replaced with another way to compute a typical/base value. Could be another quantile, for example. Or one could fit a statistical distribution and use its center. Presumably an asymmetrical long-tailed one for this case, like exponential/gamma etc.